# unordered_map and virtual template

Tags: c++, stl

The problem is: I want to use unordered_map to store keys and values, where the key can be either class A or class B, depending on the users options. Both classes A and B inherit  from the same class P.

```
class A: public P {...}
class B: public P {...}
```

I would like to define the map with the abstract P class and later, depending on runtime options, assign there a map with A or with B as a key:

```
unordered_map< P, CValue, P::hash, P::equal_to> * pmap = new unordered_map< A, CValue, A::hash, A::equal_to>;
```

but I will get error:

```
 cannot convert ... in initialization
```

How can I declare such a "virtual" map?

Comment: So we have map_unordered, unordered_map and unsorted_map - is it asking too much for you to get a simple name right?

Comment: Can you give an example on how this is going to be used? Also, do you need a map with heterogeneous keys, or do you need a family of maps with homogeneous keys?

Comment: At the beginning of the code I choose what type key will I use: A or B, and it will be used all the time later in the program. But I cannot "statically" define map template, as the key type depends on the user's option. In this particular case, I will use it to count some network statistics and I want to aggregate them by prefix _or_ by AS number.

Comment: You could make the key type a std::tuple<A,B> and then just one of the two entries; or you could make a small abstract wrapper class which is implemented by two derived classes that use different maps for the storage... would that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example how you can make the map keyed on `P*` but still use different implementations in the derived classes:

```
struct P
{
  virtual size_t hash_self() const = 0;
  virtual bool equal(const P &) const = 0;
};

struct A : public P
{
  inline bool operator==(const A & other) const { return false; /*Implement!*/}
  size_t hash_self() const { return 1; /*Implement!*/ }
  bool equal(const P & p) const { return *this == dynamic_cast<const A &>(p); }
};

struct PHash
{
  size_t operator()(const P * const p) const { return p->hash_self(); }
};

struct PEqual
{
  bool operator()(const P * const p, const P * const q) const { return p->equal(*q); }
};


#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<P *, double, PHash, PEqual> pmap{{ new A, .5 }};
```

The dynamic cast is valid because you promise only to compare pointers of the same derived type.

If you wanted to be cleaner, you could probably specialise `std::hash<P*>` and `std::equal_to<P*>`:

```
namespace std
{
  template<> struct hash<P*>
  { size_t operator()(P * const & p) const { return p->hash_self(); } };

  template<> struct equal_to<P*> : public binary_function<P*, P*, bool>
  { bool operator()(P * const & p, P * const & q) const { return p->equal(*q); } };
}

std::unordered_map<P *, int> qmap{{new A, -11}}; // just works!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
unsorted_map< P, CValue, P::hash, P::equal_to> * pmap = new unsorted_map< A, CValue, A::hash, A::equal_to>;
```

The type `P` is not same as type `A`.

So `X<P>` is a different type than `X<A>`. That means, this code

```
X<P> *pX = new X<A>();
```

wouldn't compile, even if `A` is derived from `P`. GCC would give this error ([ideone](http://www.ideone.com/BXR0V)):

```
error: cannot convert ‘X<A>*’ to ‘X<P>*’ in initialization
```

which is self-explanatory if you know that `X<A>` is a completely different type than `X<P>`.

Note that its `A` which is derived from `P`.  But `X<A>` is still NOT derived from `X<P>`. I think you're confusing the latter with the former.

So what I think you need is this:

```
unorder_map<P*, P::hash, P::equal_to>  objectMap;
```

You can insert object of type `A*` into this map:

```
objectMap.insert(new A());
```

You can insert object of type `B*` also:

```
objectMap.insert(new B());
```

After all, you want to treat all objects in the map polymorphically.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. If I have different hash functions for A and for B, how should I apply them? Once I declare objectMap and I know if I should use A or B, can I do something like objectMap::hash = A::hash?